# Reports from Jenkins and Jira

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, jira, jira-rest-api

We are using Jenkins to run the selenium automation tests and my manager wants to see the list of failed builds and what percentage of the tests passed for the builds. We also have manual tests that get executed in JIRA. I need to combine both and derive the test metrics from them.

The way I think of proceeding is as follows:

1. Get the Jenkins data in JIRA first using the Jenkins plugin for JIRA.
2. Use the jira api to collect the testing results from Jenkins and manual tests run on jira.
3. Prepare a dashboard in JIRA to display all the metrics

Could you suggest if the above approach is correct and suggest something additional.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using cucumber? In that case you could use the [cucumber reporting plugin for jenkins](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting). If it doesn't suit your needs but you still use cucumber you can also generate reports in a format like JSON, which you could later parse and get your data.

I have the feeling what you want to do seems a bit complicated, and with not a big benefit. If the tests are failing it's likely you'll have to see what is happening. Having the percentage is sure nice, but I think you can spend some hours/days tailoring this just for having something *cute* that *your manager wants* but that has no specific purpose. I would opt for something simpler.

- If the automated tests fail, create a jira issue automatically with jenkins. You could put the build number as a tag, or in the title. You can also create it always to indicate that build nr. ## was tested and everything went ok.
- As a part of the manual testing process, report in jira what failed.
- Create a dashboard and play a bit with tags and search to show which builds failed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [AssertThat BDD & Test Management in Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219033/assertthat-bdd-test-management-in-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)

Provides end-to-end integration - from features creation to manual and automated tests execution and reporting. Out of the box integration with test automation frameworks through plugins.

The plugin allows to download feature files stored in Jira before the run, execute the test in the usual way and then upload cucumber tests results back to Jira, which gives you a clear view on the testing progress in one place.

More info and usage examples on website https://www.assertthat.com/